# What does it mean that thread_local is not used inside thread?

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
int thread_local y = 4;

int main() {
   y++;
   return 0;
}
```

What does it mean that variable `y` is used not in thread (in `main` function) - there are no threads spawned? Is a main thread counted also as "normal" thread?

Comment: What does it mean that variable y is used not in thread - is it a compiler warning or someone told you that?

Comment: nah, it works correctly, y is 5 after it's increased

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a main thread counted also as "normal" thread?

Yes.

Comment: Going for the "reversal" badge?!

Comment: Wow that's interesting. I posted practically the exact same message (a bit more) and got 3 downvotes.

Comment: @stefan: You probably got downvoted for incorrectly saying that "`thread_local` is just a name".

Comment: @MikeSeymour How is that incorrect?! It's a plain old variable identifier. It's easier calling it a "name"

Comment: @stefan: No, `y` is the name. `thread_local` is the storage class specifier, meaning there's a separate copy of the variable for each thread. It was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ouch, wow. How could I miss the `y`?! It's apparently not my day.